# Outlook 365 vs Professional [save mailitem] Encoding Issues

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

I have an outlook addin currently in development that reads mail properties from outlook and displays on a winform.

I built the outlook on an environment with outlook professional 2013. All functionalities are good. Properties like, sendername, from, to etc..gets readably displayed on a winform.

This is how i access the properties of a mail.

```
Outlook.MailItem mail;
mail.Sender.Name;
```

Now, If i take the addin on an environment with the same system locale but different outlook (Outlook 365)

I experience decoding issues when trying to read some particular mails. So for example if i am accessing a mail from sender : Adèle

```
Outlook.MailItem mail;
mail.Sender.Name; // ---> This returns Ad?le
```

The mail has a UTF-8 encoding when i checked with [outlook spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm). The PC locales are the same.

One weird thing is, I copied the mail from the outlook 365 environment to the other (outlook professional) and have the issue, but when i copy the mail and import from the outlook professional environment to the outlook 365, it works correctly. So i think this has to do with the way outlook 365 saves or represents it's objects ? How can i approach this issue ? Is it fixable on my end ?

Comment: Can you check the exact version numbers of your Outlook installations? Also make sure you have identical settings in *Options > Advanced > International Options* (I assume you already made sure that you access the same message from the same sender on both systems?)

Comment: @DirkVollmar Will present my findings 2moro when i am on the system, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model (just like all IDispatch-friendly COM libraries) returns strings in the UTF-16 (2 bytes) encoding.

Make sure you display strings in a way that does not convert strings to a single byte encoding.

Do you see the same problem in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author)?

Comment: outlook spy displays the data correctly :) what does it do differently ? Do i need to do any conversions or further steps other than accessing the mailitem object property directly as described ? Thanks

Comment: You need to show your code from the moment you read the property to the moment it gets displayed. What does MessageBox.Show(mail.Sender.Name) display?